# fastest way of inserting into cassandra using python cassandra driver

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, datastax-python-driver

I am inserting and updating multiple entries into a table in Cassandra using python Cassandra driver. Currently my code looks like:

```
cluster = Cluster()
session = cluster.connect('db')
for a in list:
    if bool:
        # calculate b
        session.execute("UPDATE table SET col2 = %s WHERE col1 = %s", (b, a))
    else:
        # calculate b
        session.execute("INSERT INTO table(col1, col2) VALUES(%s, %s)", (a, b))
```

This method of insertion and update is quite slow as the number of entries in the list (all are unique) which are to be inserted is very large. Is there any faster way of doing this?

Comment: use `Session.execute_async` method with prepared statement

Comment: where `bool` comes from? it is a built-in class name, don't use it for your objects

Comment: @AzatIbrakov does execute_async() execute the queries in order? If it is so, then I can execute many queries using execute_async() and just call result() on the ResponseFuture object returned by the last call to session.execute_async(), right? If no, then what should I do to ensure all queries have been executed(i.e. all inserts have completed)?

Comment: what do you mean by "in order"? they are supposed to be asynchronous, why would you need order at all?

Answer (score 0):

Generally for this scenario, you will see the best performance by increasing the number of concurrent writes to Cassandra.

You can do this with the Datastax Python Cassandra driver using [execute_concurrent](https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra/concurrent.html#cassandra.concurrent.execute_concurrent)

From your description, it is worth noting that for your case there is no difference between an `Update` and an `Insert` with Cassandra. (i.e. you can simply do the insert statement from your else clause for all values of (a, b).

You will want to create a prepared statement.

Rather than doing the inserts one at a time in your for-loop, consider pre-computing groups of (a,b) pairs as input for `execute_concurrent`; you can also write a generator or generator expression as input for `execute_concurrent`.

Example:

```
parameters = ((a, calculate_b(a)) for a in my_list)
execute_concurrent_with_args(my_session, my_prepared_statement, parameters)
```